# Custom authentication raises 400 instead of 403

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have written a custom authentication that should return 403 incase of unauthorised login (i.e. when user exists but is not allowed to login). Here is my code:

```
def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
    # do something
        if not results:
            if not user.has_perm('some_permission'):
                raise PermissionDenied("Insufficient permission")
    return None
```

In `settings.py` I have added this custom authentication before `ModelBackend`. However, I notice that 400 is returned instead of 403. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `authenticate` function (not the method in the authentication backend) catches the `PermissionDenied` as seen in the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/225d96533a8e05debd402a2bfe566487cc27d95f/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L75-L79):

> ```
> try:
>     user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)
> except PermissionDenied:
>     # This backend says to stop in our tracks - this user should not be allowed in at all.
>     break
> ```

As indicated in the comment in the code above a `PermissionDenied` basically indicates to the function that this user should not be allowed to authenticate and not to try with the other backends. Hence `authenticate` ends up returning `None`. To actually return a response with a status code 403 you would have to do that in your *view* itself and not your authentication backend.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by importing `PermissionDenied` from rest_framework instead of default django exceptions.

Changed from

`from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied`

to

`from rest_framework.exceptions import PermissionDenied`